# Using tikz in a math environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, amsmath, tikz-styles

How would I do something like the below(the left most one) in a regular math environment? Is it a `overlay` option? Please let me know.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if you need tikz to do that. For example `$\underbrace{\underbrace{\underbrace{126}_{3?}0}_{4?}0}_{5?}$` is almost the first one, there is some spacing to be corrected. `$\underbrace{1.26}_{\substack{3\text{ SFs}\\ \text{\ldots precise to }\pm 100 \text{ ft}}}$` is the second one. This is not a complete answer but a hint.

Comment: @Dave2627  please see if the answer meets the left most figure provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this--

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, positioning, fit, shapes.misc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calc}
\tikzset{brace/.style={decorate, decoration={brace}},
    brace mirrored/.style={decorate, decoration={brace,mirror}},
}
\begin{document}
    \tikzmark{a}126\tikzmark{b}0\tikzmark{c}0\tikzmark{d} ft
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[brace mirrored, thick](pic cs:a)--(pic cs:b) node[midway, below]{3?};
        \draw[brace mirrored, thick]($(pic cs:a)+(0pt, -12pt)$)--($(pic cs:c)+(0pt, -12pt)$) node[midway, below]{4?};   
        \draw[brace mirrored, thick]($(pic cs:a)+(0pt, -24pt)$)--($(pic cs:d)+(0pt, -24pt)$) node[midway, below]{5?};           
        \draw[dotted](pic cs:c)--($(pic cs:c)+(0pt, -12pt)$);
        \draw[dotted](pic cs:d)--($(pic cs:d)+(0pt, -24pt)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    
\end{document}
```